# Accessing list names

Tags: r, list

I have a question regarding a list.

This is my data set:

```
# DATA
mydat <- data.frame(EAN=c(rep(250, 4), rep(251, 3), rep(252, 6)), 
                    NO = c(rep(0.5, 5), 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1),
                    VAR = 0)
```

Some work on the data set:

```
# SPLIT BY "EAN"
sp <- split(mydat, mydat$EAN)


# INDICES OF DUPLICATED ROWS
fkt  <- function(x) {
           which(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x[nrow(x):1, ])[nrow(x):1]) 
        }
ldup <- lapply(sp, fkt)


# SET VALUES ACCORDING TO RULE
sp$`250`$VAR[ldup$`250`] <- 1
sp$`252`$VAR[ldup$`252`] <- 1
sp$`251`$VAR[ldup$`251`] <- 1
```

Is there a nice R-way of doing this without using each of the names `"250"`, `"251"`, and `"252"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the names():

```
> sp[ names(sp)[1] ]
$`250`
  EAN  NO VAR
1 250 0.5   0
2 250 0.5   0
3 250 0.5   0
4 250 0.5   0

> sp[ names(sp)[2] ]
$`251`
  EAN  NO VAR
5 251 0.5   0
6 251 3.0   0
7 251 4.0   0


> sp[ names(sp)[3] ]
$`252`
   EAN NO VAR
8  252  1   0
9  252  1   0
10 252  1   0
11 252  2   0
12 252  1   0
13 252  1   0
```

Then you can do the assignment as :

```
sp[[ names(sp)[1] ]]$VAR[ ldup[[ names(sp)[1] ]] ] <- 1
sp[[ names(sp)[2] ]]$VAR[ ldup[[ names(sp)[2] ]] ] <- 1
sp[[ names(sp)[3] ]]$VAR[ ldup[[ names(sp)[3] ]] ] <- 1
```